# How does a custom function used in a Keras layer obtain its arguments?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I know how to define and utilize custom functions (say, a loss function) can be defined to be passed to a Keras layer. However, I don't understand how this function considers its arguments from the model.

For e.g.:

Let the following be the definitions of the custom loss function:

```
def kl_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_var - K.square(mean_mu) - K.exp(log_var), axis = 1)
    return kl_loss

def r_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis = [1,2,3])

def total_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return LOSS_FACTOR*r_loss(y_true, y_pred) + kl_loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

Having defined this custom loss function, I call pass it to the Keras model as follows:

```
model.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, loss = total_loss, metrics = [r_loss, kl_loss])
```

The above works perfectly, however, I don't understand how the Keras model passes on the values of `y_true` and `y_pred` to the functions.

Code credits: https://towardsdatascience.com/generating-new-faces-with-variational-autoencoders-d13cfcb5f0a8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my understanding,

the function (total_loss) that is specified as the loss during compiling gets the true value and predicted value of a sample implicitly.